# RadioButtonList Sending empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am creating a Sign Up web form in ASP.net, but on client side it is sending empty string as I have selected one option, what is the reason behind it and how can I get the non-empty string.

Here is my code for RadioButtonList.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="listGender" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="M">Male</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="F">Female</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

And here is my jQuery code.

```
// Validate for Gender Selection
if ($('#listGender').val().trim() == "") {
  $('#spGender').html('Please select one option');
  validate = false;
} else {
  $('#spGender').html('');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID change on run time so you cant catch this via same ID.

1.Use  `ClientIDMode="Static"`  to get same ID

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="listGender" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <asp:ListItem Value="M">Male</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="F">Female</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

2.Use classical approach.

```
$("< %= listGender.ClientID %>");
```

Comment: Dear Shree thank you for your answer but both does not work for me instead i use $("input[id*=listGender]") and it worked thank you again

Comment: You are using wild card which match all id which contain  `listGender`. This is not best practice . Follow one of my approach. Try to understand your code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For Radio Button List you can also use this:

```
$("input[id*=listGender]")
```